# How to tell if internal link is pointing to a static resource?

Tags: ruby, parsing, dom

I am using Ruby to find/store all links in a web page that is pointing to another resource (like another HTML page).

Obviously, links like the below are real links:

```
<a href="/resource">Dummy 3</a>
```

I am encountering links like the below that are not truly links to resources:

```
<a href="#">Dummy</a>
<a href="javascript:void()">Dummy 2</a> //a javascript link could redirect me to another resource, but I am not interested in these
```

I'm trying to come up with a rule on excluding links like the 2 above.

Is there other links I should be excluding, aside from "#", and anything that starts with "javascript:" ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to use a gem for that? Some people already did the job to get this kind of information and you could use it as well.

I quickly find one but there is a few.
Take a look:
https://github.com/alexpeattie/nitlink#usage

Comment: I actually don't want to extract all internal links. I want to check if a link is really a link to a resource. The way I phrased the question is just so I can make it easier for ppl to understand what I want.